# Proving that DCONN is NL-Complete

Tags: reductions, decision-problem

I am having trouble with some homework regarding proving that DCONN is NL-Complete. As part of the exercise, the fact that RCH is NL-Complete can be assumed.

Problem definitions:

> RCH: Given a directed graph G and nodes x, y , is there a path from x to y?

> DCONN: given a directed graph G, is it connected?

To my understanding we have have to prove two things:

1. $ DCONN \leq RCH$
2. $RCH \leq DCONN$

**Reduction** $\leq $ in this case is defined as:
$L$ is logspace-reducible to $L^{'}$ ($L \leq_{log} L{'})$ iff there is a LOGSPACE function f such that: $x \in L$ iff $f(x) \in L{'}$.

To be honest I have no idea where to even start. The following is my naive attempt to tackle the first issue.
For the first part I thought that running $n^2$ RCH questions to see if node $y$ is reachable from node $x$ for all $x,y \in G, x \neq y$ will be sufficient to prove that $G$ is connected or not. But I am not sure if that is sufficient to be considered a reduction.

When it comes to the second part I have no idea where to even start. Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: *I am not sure if that is sufficient to be considered a reduction.* If you don't know the notion of reductions in this case, you cannot expect to be able to prove that a reduction exists. Before attempting the exercise, make sure that you know the formal definition of reduction which is relevant here.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I've updated the question to contain the correct definition of reduction relative to this context.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you've solved the problem but here's some of my thoughts:

For the first part, running $n^2$ $RCH$ should be a log space reduction since you only require $O(logn)$ extra space to record which pair you are currently checking.

For the second part, for each $<G,s,t>$ you can construct a graph $G'$ where:

- For each vertice $x\neq s$, add the edge $(x,s)$
- For each vertice $y\neq t$, add the edge $(t,y)$

Then run $DCONN$ on $<G',s,t>$. You can see $RCH(<G,s,t>)=1$ if and only if $DCONN(<G',s,t>)=1$.
As for the reduction (the extra cost for $G'$ construction), since the vertices remain the same and the edges are at most tripled, this should also be a log space reduction. You can think of it as a polynomial change to the $DCONN$ input.

Answer (score 1):

**To show that $\text{DCONN}$ is in $\text{NL}$:** you can use the fact that $RCH\in \text{NL}$ and the fact that $\text{NL} = \text{coNL}$.
So we have a nondeterministic TM $T$ that decides $\overline{RCH}$ using at most logarithmic space. Now note that a directed graph $G = \langle V, E\rangle$ is not connected iff there are distinct nodes $u, v\in V$ such that there is no path from $u$ to $v$. Hence, we can decide $\overline{\text{DCONN}}$ in nondeterministic logspace by guessing two vertices $u$ and $v$, and then operate as the machine $T$ to check whether there is no path from $u$ to $v$. So we got that $\overline{\text{DCONN}}\in \text{NL}$, and as $\text{NL}=\text{coNL}$, we conclude that $\text{DCONN}\in \text{NL}$. Note that guessing and writing the vertices $u$ and $v$ takes at most logspace since we can write the address or the number that corresponds to a vertex in binary.

**To show that $\text{DCONN}$ is in $\text{NL-hard}$:** we define a logspace reduction from $\text{RHC}$ to $\text{DCONN}$: on input $\langle G, x, y\rangle$, the reduction outputs the graph $G'$ that is obtained from $G$ by adding the directed edges $(v, x)$ and $(y, v)$ for every vertex $v$ of $G$. Clearly, the reduction is correct. Indeed, if there is a path $p$ from $x$ to $y$ in $G$, the for all $u, v\in V$, $v, p, u$ is a path from $u$ to $v$ in $G'$, and thus $G'$ is connected. Conversely, if there is no path from $x$ to $y$ in $G$, then there is no path from $x$ to $y$ in $G'$ and thus $G'$ is not connected. Indeed, if by contradiction there is a path $p$ from $x$ to $y$ in $G'$, then we can assume that $p$ is simple by omitting cycles from it. Now as $p$ is simple, starts with $x$ and ends with $y$, we get that $p$ does not use any of the new added edges as these edges are directed to $x$ or directed from $y$. Hence, $p$ exists also in $G$, and we've reached a contradiction.

Also note that the reduction can be implemented using at most logspace as follows. The Turing machine $M$ the computes the reduction follows the standard  3-Tape model, thus we have an input, work, and output tape, and the space complexity is defined w.r.t work tape. $M$ operates as follows. On input $\langle G = \langle V, E\rangle, x, y\rangle$, $M$ copies $\langle G\rangle$ to its output tape without using any space at all. Then, $M$, loops over all vertices $v\in V$ and appends the edges $(v, x), (y, v)$ to the description of $G$ in its output tape. So the only space that $M$ uses is the binary address for the current vertex $v$. So in a sense, $M$ keeps track only of the number of the current vertex in its loop.